# qt-quick(qml) application can't subscribe ros topic

Tags: cmake, qmake, ros, qt-quick, catkin

After watching the video tutorial below,

https://youtu.be/NG05o_SV1iw

I could learn how to open catkin project from "Qt Creator."
Now I need to make Qt-Quick application subscribe ros topic.
But, I don't know how. Some facts on this issue are:

- Qt-Quick application is compiled using qmake
- catkin project is compiled using cmake
  (*In catkin project ros topic can be subscribed.)

In short, please let me know "how to make qt-quick application be compiled using cmake.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample CMakeList.txt file that can be used to compile a QT application in ROS. Its for QT5 (the ros qt package seems to only support qt4)

To make it work with your project just replace your CMakeList.txt file and change all the paths/project names:

```
##############################################################################
# CMake
##############################################################################

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.0)
project(gui)

##############################################################################
# Catkin
##############################################################################

# qt_build provides the qt cmake glue, roscpp the comms for a default talker
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS qt_build roscpp sensor_msgs image_transport)
set(QML_IMPORT_PATH "${QML_IMPORT_PATH};${CATKIN_GLOBAL_LIB_DESTINATION}" )
set(QML_IMPORT_PATH2 "${QML_IMPORT_PATH};${CATKIN_GLOBAL_LIB_DESTINATION}" )
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
# Use this to define what the package will export (e.g. libs, headers).
# Since the default here is to produce only a binary, we don't worry about
# exporting anything. 
catkin_package()

##############################################################################
# Qt Environment
##############################################################################

# this comes from qt_build's qt-ros.cmake which is automatically 
# included via the dependency ca ll in package.xml
#rosbuild_prepare_qt4(QtCore QtGui QtQml QtQuick) # Add the appropriate components to the component list here
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Gui Qml Quick REQUIRED)

##############################################################################
# Sections
##############################################################################

file(GLOB QT_RESOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} resources/*.qrc)
file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_MOC RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS include/gui/*.hpp)

QT5_ADD_RESOURCES(QT_RESOURCES_CPP ${QT_RESOURCES})
QT5_WRAP_CPP(QT_MOC_HPP ${QT_MOC})

##############################################################################
# Sources
##############################################################################

file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS src/*.cpp)

##############################################################################
# Binaries
##############################################################################

add_executable(gui ${QT_SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${QT_FORMS_HPP} ${QT_MOC_HPP})
qt5_use_modules(gui Quick Core)
target_link_libraries(gui ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(gui PUBLIC include)
install(TARGETS gui RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
```

There is a more detailed explanation at the [source article](http://bluesat.com.au/streaming-video-to-a-gui-with-ros-and-qml-part-1/). But basically the important parts are:

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Qml Quick REQUIRED)
```

Which imports Qt5 core, qml and quick components. If you are not using qml you can safely remove that part. You should also be able to add other qml components here.

The additional qt5 functions in the cmake list do thinks like running the qt5 prepossessor on your header file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a Qt GUI interface connected and communicating with ROS, you might take a look at this [ROS Qt](http://wiki.ros.org/qt_ros) package.
It has a tutorial and templates on how exactly to acheive that. It can be used as a starting point for your project as well.

Also, it comes with a ros_create_qt_package command which creates a template of Qt GUI and ROS package already ready to go, so you have just to costumize it as u wish.

and at last, just an ordinar catkin_make is necessary, so you don't get lost in between all the different make commands (Thanks CMakeLists !).

Cheers,

Comment: It's worth warning people that `ros_create_qt_package` creates a **Qt 4** package, so you can't use it with QML, and you also can't link against recent versions of rqt, qviz, or other tools that use Qt 5.